# Problem when opening nvidia x server settings program

Tags: drivers

as you can see here in screenshot the nvidia x server settings program is installed but when i click it, simple nothing happens... this is a very strange problem..

[image]

I want to connect my laptop with hdmi and with a quick search on google i must do it with that program...Any ideas?

Comment: Try running it from Terminal with 'nvidia-settings' then post the results if it still doesn't open.

Comment: nvidia-settings: command not found

Comment: i searched in google and found this : http://www.noobslab.com/2011/09/nvidia-drivers-for-ubuntu-1110-oneiric.html... i runned these 3 commands, restarted and the same...

Comment: i searched for the .desktop file and it says Exec:/usr/bin/nvidia-settings but the file is missing..

Comment: Try 'sudo apt-get install nvidia-settings'

Comment: well i haven't thought to install it cause i was seeing it on unity.. Thanks it works.. Should i report this at ubuntu at launchpad?

Comment: Please post an answer to your question (or we can flag it for deletion if you want), we don't do [solved] here, you can post your answer and then accept it as the correct one.

Comment: oo ok sorry then. I am newbie here. Well should i click on answer your question and say that i runned sudo apt-get install nvidia-settings and fixed my problem?

Comment: well i did but i can't accept it..

Comment: @Bong.Da.City After posting an answer to your own question, you have to wait 2 days before the system will let you mark it as the accepted answer. (But it's encouraged to do so then, if it's the best answer.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install **nvidia-settings** from Software Center:

[image: Install via the software center]

Or run in Terminal:

```
sudo apt-get update  
sudo apt-get install nvidia-settings
```

It fixed my problem!

Answer (score 0):

`sudo apt-get install nvidia-settings-319-updates` solved my problem (I installed nvidia driver 319).